# How to send an object of a class to database for storing in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting data from a form and retrieve it in action method of a controller.Here I storing it in an object of a class named as User Class. Then I want to store it in database, for this I created an object of Model of database. Then I am trying to pass user class object to database Model by Implementing it as in code below, but it giving error that can not convert youtube.Models.user to Youtube.Models.Registerations.

```
 //Form
 <form method="post">
        <span class="form-group ">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname"  name="Fname" required>
        </span>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" name="Lname" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname"  name="uname" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd"  name="pswd" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label>Confirm Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="cpswd" required>
        </div>
        <div id="invalid"></div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SignUp" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

[image: User Class]

[image: Controller]

[image: Project Directory]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Register method, you are creating an object of User model. But this line

```
youtube.Registration.Add();
```

tells the entity framework that you are trying to add an object of Registration model but you are passing an object of user model that why it is showing error.

Create an object of registration model and then initialize its properties and then add that in ef like this -

```
Registration registration = new Registration();
resgistration.YourPropertyName1 = "SomeValue";
......
youtube.Registration.Add(registration);
youtube.SaveChanges();
```

Similarly for User model -

```
youtube.User.Add(user);
youtube.SaveChanges();
```

You get the idea, right?

Comment: Yeah I got it , Thanks a lot for help.